# What is the solution to achieve the maximum of this function? Does there exist a closed-form expression of the solution?

Tags: closed-form

We have a function of $x$, which is given by
\begin{equation}
f(x)=\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}
\end{equation}
where $x \geq 0$.

Question: Does there exist a closed-form expression for the optimal $x$ that achieves the maximum of $f(x)$?

##### My approach

Let the derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ equal $0$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{2x(e^x-1)-x^2e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}&=0  \\
\Rightarrow 2x(e^x-1)-x^2e^x&=0 \qquad (1)\\ 
\Rightarrow e^x(2-x)&=2
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
It seems that the above equation $(1)$ does not have a closed-form solution.

Comment: Note that $f(0)$ is indeterminate, but we can use L'Hôpital's rule to show that $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$ and that's clearly the minimum of the function in the domain $x\ge 0$. FWIW, here's a [graph](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwdzEsKgCAQANB9pxBpYaD9oKU3icJsEmHSGF0E0d2Tlm_zLoxZ3MvYCVhuNTSSCdW3k2RjOxU48jv6AEnz04dIXFYMwUHYVzQboCZezwcZ-5Tjff7jrblkJl1g80om-6iH5gNXeyDD&lang=sage).

Comment: Thank @PM 2Ring for correcting the grammatical errors in this question! 
^-^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only non trivial explicit solution of
$$e^x(2-x)=2$$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
$$x_*=2+W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)\sim 1.59362$$
$$f(x_*)=-W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right) \left(W\left(-\frac{2}{e^2}\right)+2\right)\sim 0.64761$$

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: @HiBlank. You are welcome. I suggest you look at this beautiful function which has more and more applications. On the search bar of this site, just type *Lambert*; you will find $3616$ results ! Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks! I have searched the item “Lambert W Function” through this site and the Wiki, and I find helpful information about this function!
^-^!

Comment: @HiBlank. I felt in love with Lambert function 64+ years ago. Look at simple applications on this site. You will be surprised. Glad to make you knowing it ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I admire you insistence in the Lamber function!
I can not believe that you can keep in love with a funciton so long time!
It is amazing and wonderful! 
Cheers ^-^!

Comment: @HiBlank The Lambert W function is very useful in problems like this, but it does take a bit of practice to learn how to manipulate an equation into a form where you can use the Lambert W. Fortunately, there are lots of examples on this site, many of them written by Claude. ;)

Comment: @HiBlank BTW, if you don't have access to the Lambert W, you can easily find the root of your equation using Newton's method. Here's a short [Sage / Python script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9jMEKgzAQRO_5ijnupI0SKR4KfoygLbmkEnqYz3dVcGFgZ9_MChNyN4bPr6GgVLS5fld78R3gs8i5DUiQa4irNksi0cOOS-YZEx6TZ899a6X-TU_3DLc5imK8XvEGUb1dKGVyB66uJC0=&lang=sage) that shows how, (although Sage does have Lambert W).

Comment: @PM 2Ring Thanks a lot. 
It really takes long time for me to slove this problem with a closed form solution!